# find: "show -printf only" when "-exec returns 0"

Tags: find

What I have:

```
/usr/bin/find /my_directory -type f -not -empty -name '*.log' -printf '%T@ %Tc %p\n' -exec grep 'text in file' {} \;
```

This will show all non-empty log files in `/my_directory`:

```
1619942263.2701036230 Sun May  2 09:57:43 2021 /my_directory/abc.log
1619945861.8521817540 Sun May  2 10:57:41 2021 /my_directory/def.log
```

But I only want to get files with `text in file` - in this or a similar style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place `-exec` before `-printf`:

```
find /my_directory -type f -not -empty -name '*.log' -exec grep -q 'text in file' {} \; -printf '%T@ %Tc %p\n'
```

`-exec` evaluates to false if the command exits with a non-zero exit code, and subsequent actions are skipped.